# Java Spring: main method is called duplicate

Tags: java, spring-boot

The main method is called duplicate.
How I can prevent this?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main "+args);
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Running with below command

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

Output

```
main [Ljava.lang.String;@1cf4f579
main [Ljava.lang.String;@1cf4f579 <------- I cannot understand THIS.
```

`pom.xml`: dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.18</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: How do you run your program? On the command line, in an IDE...?

Comment: I am running project with `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: What dependencies do you have? Specifically, do you have spring-boot-devtools on your classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by spring-boot-devtools. If you have that dependency in your classpath, devtools will automatically register and restart your application on any changes to files in the classpath. This can also be seen in the log statements, since all logs will be logged from the thread "restartedMain", instead of "main" like in a Spring Boot application without devtools.

Log with devtools:

```
2021-03-08 21:27:05.508  INFO 25824 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.MyApplication           : Starting MyApplication
```

Log without devtools:

```
2021-03-08 21:24:06.624  INFO 3652 --- [           main] com.example.demo.MyApplication           : Starting MyApplication
```

In short: This is expected behaviour and shouldn't cause any problems, since (1) you shouldn't run any additional code in the main method of a Spring Boot application anyway and (2) you shouldn't package spring-boot-devtools in the production version of your application.

Comment: yes, i installed `devtools`, but, that's function is not same with `nodemon`

Comment: Not sure what you mean with nodemon, haven't heard that in combination with Spring Boot.

Comment: https://nodemon.io/  : nodemon is node development tools: to restart project after file change